# mail is not sending using codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, view, model

I want to send an email to users when they registered.
i have used email api to send mail to user.

my controller code:

```
$this->load->model('user_model');
$verify = $this->user_model->insertUser();
$this->verifyMail($username,$verify);
$user_data = array(
    'email' => $email,
    'username' => $username,
    'logged_in' => TRUE 
);
$this->SendMail();
$this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
redirect('user/about_me');
```

my mail code :

```
function SendMail()
{
    //***************Email API ***********************************************************
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: HP <crm@example.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "CC: hp@example.com\r\n";   

    $mailbox= "<pre style=\"font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;\">
                test
                </pre>";

    $Subject = "Ttest \r\n" ;

    $email_to = "hp@example.com" ;

    if($email_to != '') {
        mail($email_to, $Subject, $mailbox, $headers);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to set the user data before you send the email and include the user data inside SendMail.

Here are the changes:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
$this->SendMail();

$email_to = $this->session->userdata("email");
```

Here is the full example:

```
$this->load->model('user_model');
$verify = $this->user_model->insertUser();
$this->verifyMail($username,$verify);
$user_data = array(
    'email' => $email,
    'username' => $username,
    'logged_in' => TRUE 
);
$this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
$this->SendMail();
redirect('user/about_me');


function SendMail()
{
    //***************Email API ***********************************************************
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: HP <crm@example.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "CC: hp@example.com\r\n";   

    $mailbox= "<pre style=\"font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;\">
                test
                </pre>";

    $Subject = "Ttest \r\n" ;

    $email_to = $this->session->userdata("email");

    if($email_to != '') {
        mail($email_to, $Subject, $mailbox, $headers);
    }       
}
```

Comment: I have fix email id then what is use of this code
$email_to = $this->session->userdata("email"); . This is same as 'hp@example.com'. And From your code it is not working

Comment: Since you were putting the email address into the session, I thought it should be recalled in the SendMail() function for use in sending the email.  I saw the 'hp@example.com' and figured that was a hard coded address that doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you tried verifying that the mail() is working. In a new controller function hard code the mail function. Send an email to your personal email.

Comment: mail('myemail@example.com','some text','some more text');